# Progressive filtering with tags

Tags: completion, tags

I don't know how to name this functionality that I want.

I am sure it exists.

So What I want to do is similar to when you apply "tags", output is shown. Then you can choose to apply more tags on the existing output.

I don't see this functionality no where.

How this could be useful is as followed.
Given that you have 4 types of search functionality.

1. search tags
2. search files name
3. search text within files.
4. search symbols

you can imagine applying search sequence in different order depends on information that you have gather from previous search output.

This functionality seems intuitive and obvious for anyone to look pass it.

but I failed to find one, and I don't have time to implement from scratch yet.

Comment: The question isn't too clear. Are you asking how to tag information (e.g. files, buffers)? Are you asking how to use existing tags to find information? Are you asking how to use tags with completion? Please narrow your question to be more specific, so that answers aren't guessing all over the place. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Org mode lets you tag parts of data in `org-mode`, I believe. (No doubt someone will provide an answer speaking more to that. I mention it, without knowing much about it.)

---

If you use [Bookmark+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus) then you can [tag all kinds of things](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags). Specifically, you bookmark something (a location or an object of some kind), and you add free-form tags to it. Tags are arbitrary strings, by default. But they can also be pairs of a string (the tag name/label) and a Lisp value.

You can find/access bookmarks, and thus the data they point to, using combinations of tags. For that you can use regexp matching etc.

---

If you use a decent completion framework, such as [Icicles](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) then you can [progressively match](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Progressive_Completion) bookmark names or tag names or both.